# Terminal not opening when in root mode in nautilus. What to do?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Opening nautilus in administrator mode and then opening terminal in any directory is not functioning. Trying to open it always gives out the error.

I have Ubuntu 17.04 and Unity.

[image: This image shows the error whenever I open the terminal in administrative mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a number of experiences where `terminal` wouldn't open. To work around this I created a keyboard shortcut with `dbus-launch gnome-terminal`

Perhaps creating a similar shortcut for nautilus would remedy the problem?

```
dbus-launch nautilus
```

You can try it at a command prompt and see if that is a bridge fix for you.